# IE 11.0.10 fails to display HTML updated with Javascript except when console opened

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am developing a website that builds tables dynamically via HTTP GET requests. It has a button to retrieve the data and rebuild the tables (effectively refreshing the page) via an onclick event. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, as well as in Internet Explorer - but only when the developer tools (F12) are open in IE. I can tell the Javascript successfully executes, as it modifies a global variable (used to prevent conflicting element ids), however the HTML remains unchanged.

As soon as I open the developer tools, it works exactly as expected. console functions are never called in the Javascript.

Caching is disabled both in httpd.conf and in the  tag.

I can post code as needed, but I don't know which part to post.

EDIT: As previously stated, there are NO console functions called, including console.log(). IE is set to Edge.

EDIT 2: Putting an alert in the code, as suggested in other similar questions, does not resolve the issue.

Comment: remove your console.log

Comment: @KevinB - I thought IE11 didn't have that problem with console.log and only older versions, like IE8 did.

Comment: I don't know, can't test it. What else would make it only work when the dev tools are open? he could potentially be in compatibility mode too.

Comment: Are you running IE in IE11 mode, or a compatibility mode?

Comment: @j08691 it's running in Edge.

Comment: @KevinB there is no console.log

Comment: Have you tried IE's Developer Channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out the issue: Despite it being told *twice* to disable caching, IE for some reason still was caching my Javascript GET request.

I was able to fix this by switching to a POST request.

Comment: Maybe the server was replying with a cached response, which is out of IE's control? By the way you can/should accept your own answer.

Comment: @Vache Excuse my ignorance, but how would I be able to tell if it was? Wouldn't the fact that other browsers worked fine suggest that it was a clientside issue? (Also, I apparently can't accept my own answer for two days.)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I only skimmed through the question and missed the part where it worked in other browsers.